# Custom PHP add to integrate Xero

Tags: php, xero-api

We are a screen printing company and we have developed PHP app to manage our orders. I was just wondering if its possible to convert orders from our system to invoice in xero? Would love to convert multiple orders into invoice in a single click. I am not a programmer but will be hiring one to do it, if its possible.

Comment: If you want to hire , you can post your requirement on job portal. This is not the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Xero does not have Sales Order functionality but can be used as you've said to create invoices directly from orders. It might be difficult to find someone to do this, feel free to PM me if you don't have any luck.